# Nomenclature of salts of oxyanions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

I want to know what is the way to determine a compound's composition by just seeing the name. For example, if I see the name

"copper (II) sulfate"

How would I go about deducing that its formula is CuSO<sub>4</sub>? I know that copper(II) refers to the copper cation with a +2 charge. I know sulfur can have either a -2, +4, or +6 charge. And I know that oxygen has a -2 charge. I also know that an ending of "-ate" means a high amount of oxygen. But it doesn't specify exactly *how many* oxygen atoms I'll need. I'm new to studying chemistry so excuse me if this seems like a bad question.